# What is the difference between two code in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was just starting typescript and got stuck on this issue.

I have two codes, in first code there is an object `name` and in another code (same as first code) the variable name is changed to `user`.
Now the problem is first code is creating error but first is working fine.

**First Code (Producing Error)**

```
interface Person {
    firstName : string;
    lastName  : string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var name = {firstName: "Girdhari", lastName: "Agrawal"};
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(name);
```

**Second Code (Working fine)**

```
interface Person {
    firstName : string;
    lastName  : string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = {firstName: "Girdhari", lastName: "Agrawal"};


document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Please help me to understand this.

**Edited**

```
This is what I am getting while compiling first script
greeter.ts(10,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'name' must be of type 'string', but here has type '{ firstname: string; lastName: string; }'.
greeter.ts(13,35): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
```

Comment: What's the error? Also check for any invisible characters in the non-working version.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: You are probably defining `name` somewhere else in your code as a string.

Comment: May be I am unable to get it, I am sharing two screenshots of my code

1. Error : https://snag.gy/G5m1Kx.jpg
2. Working: https://snag.gy/hiuU7L.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `name` is a [global variable defined in *lib.d.ts*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a03941237334f6757c932254d58f1833fa1b004a/lib/lib.d.ts#L18403) ([`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)):

```
declare var name: string;
```

The reason you're getting this error is because your code is also in the global scope. That's why using a different variable name works.